# vspace, hspace don't work in textblock

Tags: vspace

i use vspace, hspace in textpos (texblock) but don't work.

Please help

Thank in advance

My minimal coding:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(4.0cm,2.0cm) % 
\begin{center}
\small X
\vspace*{0.55cm}
\Huge Y
\vspace*{0.25cm} \hspace*{0.45cm}
\small Z
\end{center}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you essentially have one paragraph with all of your spaces in it (which is why you're getting the result that you're seeing.

If you include paragraph breaks along with your `\vspace` commands that should give you something closer to what you're expecting.